# Two gems share same require?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require

When I call:

```
require 'retryable'
```

These two gems clash:

- https://github.com/robertsosinski/retryable
- https://github.com/carlo/retryable

as they both have a 'retryable' file they ask the user to require. I'm interested in using the first gem, however this doesn't always happen.

This code is executed as a part of my own gem, and it has to be reliable across all users.

Is there a way to require specifically from a gem (as the gem names are different of course)?

How do I resolve this naming conflict?

EDIT: To clarify, this is the official repo and the gem names are actually different ("retryable-rb" and "carlo-retryable"), however they both ask their users to require the lib/retryable.rb file with `require 'retryable'`

Comment: If you download from the official Ruby Gem repository, two different gems are not allowed to have the same name, so this situation should not occur. Are you using a non-official repository?

Comment: If you are only interested in the first gem, why not uninstall the second one? Are you going to use it in some other occasion?

Comment: Anyway, the first gem is two years old, and the second one is three years old. I don't think it is a good choice to use them.

Comment: The gem names are actually different "retryable-rb" and "carlo-retryable" but they still have the same "retryable" file as a require. Yes I could only have one installed, but I can't ask my users to run bundler every-time they want to use my gem, and what if they need to use the other one at the same time? They are both old gems yes, it's very simple code too, but I still would like a solution to this problem.

Comment: Fork it and rename it?

Comment: I could not find the gem [carlo-retryable](http://rubygems.org/search?query=carlo-retryable).

Comment: Guilherme Bernal: Ah right, it got moved and is now called only 'retryable'. It's now under https://github.com/nfedyashev/retryable. What a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly activate a specific gem with the [`gem` method](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Kernel.html#method-i-gem).

In this case you want the `retryable-rb` gem, and not any others that may have a `retryable.rb` file:

```
gem 'retryable-rb'   # activates the gem in question
                     # and adds its lib dir to load path

require 'retryable'  # loads retryable.rb from the retryable-rb gem, as it
                     # is now on the load path
```

Comment: This didn't do the job for me. The other gem is still the one which require loads from.

Comment: @ZirconCode If that is the case then it sounds like something is broken with your Ruby/Gem install, or something else is happening. You’re not trying to use both gems together are you?

Comment: Ah, that solution makes it work now. I had a leftover conflicting Gemfile.lock from earlier, thanks =)